# Clear all content after alert message

Tags: asp.net, forms

Newbie

I have a asp.net application
I have a barcode reader connected and when i scan a card to a textbox it gets the value from database
I the card already exists it will show a alert message
Then i want it to reload or clear all information in the form
Cant get it to work
my alert code is like this

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('This card has expired, please go to reception for assistans');", true);

Its in code behind

Answer (score 0):

You would be MUCH better to have some display or information on the web page, or even consider a toast like message.

If you popup that dialog, then the user will have to put down the scanner, click ok on the screen, then pick up the scanner, and scan again. So you don't really want to do that.

I would suggest you put some "div" box on the screen some place, and do this:

```
        <h2>Ready to scan ID</h2>

        <asp:TextBox ID="scanBox" runat="server" Width="291px"></asp:TextBox>

        <div id="MyMsg" style="display:none;color:red">

            <h2>This card has expired</h2>
            <h2>Please see front desk</h2>

        </div>
```

NOTE how we HIDE the above with style and display:none

So, you might have this:

[image]

so, when you scan, and say the card is checked etc., then you can do this in your code

```
    {
        // Expired code - display message.
        MyMsg.Style.Add("display", "normal");
```

And then the display will look like this:

[image]

So, the problem with some dialog box, when, where, how do you want the message to display, and if you present that dialog, it will remain open until the user has to click ok on that box.

So, you don't want to use "alert", since you can't close it down. You might as noted want to use some cool "toast" message, or simply have some "div" on the page that you show/hide, and thus no one will have to dismiss the box.

Comment: OK nice
Im checking if the card is valid in code behind can i put the mymsg.style.add there?
Or must it be in aspx file

Comment: sure, put it right in your code behind. I used a div, but you can place any kind of content that div and yes then in code behind hide/show as per my code. It just the dialog (confirm) is a bad idea. As noted, you could pop a toast message, or some dialog that fades out and closes on its own, or as noted, just hide/show some message content inside of a div like I did. but, yes - that code goes in code behind to hide/show the message.

Comment: Could i do like this
                else
                {
                    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "Func()", true);
                   // ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Thic card has expired, please go to reception for assistans');", true);
                MyMsg.Style.Add("display", "normal");
            }

Comment: How can i get the div to fade out after some time

Comment: different question. You could start a JavaScript client side function - and have it hide the message say after 5 seconds. if you want it to fade out, then you want to introduce say jquery.UI to do this. You can start a whole new question. Just post the few lines of code you have that shows the div, along with your question as to how to hide or fade out after x seconds - so different concept, and different question.

Comment: Can i have the page reload after the message has faded out?
The message is saved so when next card is scanned it shows the message again even if the card is ok